# in react native flatlist render function.. i'm componenting out a textinput and I am passing value through state props but onchange never fires

Tags: reactjs, react-native, onchange, textinput

The text which is set to numerical never changes and the log never appears.  This is so basic and weird that I can't get it to work.

```
const SetInput = props  => {



    return(
        <View>
        <TextInput 
                style={styles.textInput}
                keyboardType='numeric'
                onChange={props.handleSets}
                value={props.value}
                name={props.name}
                maxLength={10}  //setting limit of input
/>
        </View>
    )
  
};
```

heres the main component.... with setInput component and handleSets();  What happens is the number 4 initial state value is in the input but I can't change it and onChange never logs anything.

```
const FavoritesScreen = props  => {
const favorites = useSelector(state => state.favorites.favoritedExercises);


const [sets, setSets] = useState('4');



const dispatch = useDispatch();

const handleSets = (e) => {
    setSets(e.target.value)
   console.log('sets handled')
    
   
}


const WorkoutRenderHandler = (favorites) => {
    return(
        <SafeAreaView>
           
        <View style={styles.container}>
            
      
        <View style={styles.workoutItem}>
        <View style={styles.flexthing}>
       
            <Text numberOfLines={1} style={styles.name}> {favorites.item.name}</Text>
            {/* <Image source={{uri: favorites.item.gifUrl}} style={{width: 40, height: 40}}/> */}
            <Text style={styles.equipment}>{favorites.item.equipment}</Text>
            <SetInput onChange={handleSets}  value={sets}/>
          
           
        </View>
        </View>
        
      
        </View>
       
        </SafeAreaView>
    )
  
};






return ( 
        <ReturnedWorkoutList  data={favorites} renderItem={WorkoutRenderHandler} style={styles.screen} extaData={sets}/>
```

};

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TextInput,  } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

// You can import from local files
import AssetExample from './components/AssetExample';

// or any pure javascript modules available in npm
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';




export default function App() {
   const [formData, setData] = useState({});

   const handleSets = (e) => {
    setData({ ...formData, eventtitle: e })
    console.log('sets handled')
}
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
       <TextInput placeholder="WRITE HERE" onChangeText={value => handleSets(value)}/>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  }
});
```

DEMO: https://snack.expo.dev/@g1sm0/ryan-hartley

Comment: Thanks, but still doesn't allow me to enter a number and nothing is logged to the console.

Comment: @RyanHartley i edited my awnser above

Comment: thanks.  the function still never gets called.. I need information from the event object.  I tried useref too but no good.

Comment: how bizarre   flkadfoindfdfadfadsfaf

Comment: because I am a moron who called props.functionName instead of props.onChange...  Thank you for all of your undeserved help!!

Comment: You know its still undefined!!

Comment: PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large
    at readStream (C:\Users\rmhar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:155:17)
    at getRawBody (C:\Users\rmhar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:108:12)
    at read (C:\Users\rmhar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cl

Comment: if I use onChangeText i get this long error